# Can I access my cloud files without accessing my home computer?

Tags: ubuntu-one, cloud

What do I need to do if I am away and without my home computer and I need to access my cloud files? Can I connect using any other computer in another part of the world?

Comment: That's what cloud is about. Accessing your files(which are located at a server) from ANY computer using your account.

Answer (score 4):

You will be able to access Ubuntu One, Dropbox, Sugar Sync, 4shared, Mediafire, Google Drive and most other cloud services through their websites. From there, most of them will allow you to rename, relocate, open, download ro execute the files with password permission. This will only work with an internet connection, if you are unable to establish such a connection, I recommend using a USB which can easy match 2-20GB Storage space. 
Saying this, I do advise you to be cautious if you wish to access your account via free WiFi from Internet cafes or hotspots.

Good luck!

M

Answer (score 4):

You can Login through [Ubuntu One Cloud Storage Account](https://one.ubuntu.com/files/) to do the require modifications from any Computer and from any part of the world.

As below image , you can view your **U1 files** and **Devices** used . It also avoids installing U1 application to view your files ,since you can Access it Directly through Web Page. For **Folder** you will get Sharing options .

[image]

If you select individual files through the **Folders**, it also provides options from the Right-side corresponding **`MORE`** option to expand menu as here for PDF file.

You can Publish  `(URL address to directly download it)` it for others download .

[image]

For **On the move access** :

[**Android applications**](https://one.ubuntu.com/downloads/android/) for **Ubuntu One Files app** and **Ubuntu One Music app**

[**iPhone applications**](https://one.ubuntu.com/downloads/iphone/) both for **Ubuntu One Files app** and **Music streaming app for iPhone**. (iPhone app also works on the **iPad**)

---

Web-based common FAQ's questions

[Does Ubuntu One work with Internet Explorer?](https://one.ubuntu.com/help/faq/does-ubuntu-one-work-with-internet-explorer/)

[Can I upload large files through the web?](https://one.ubuntu.com/help/faq/can-i-upload-large-files-through-the-web/)

[Can I upload multiple files at one time via the web?](https://one.ubuntu.com/help/faq/can-i-upload-multiple-files-at-one-time-via-the-web/)

Answer (score 2):

You can access your files that you have uploaded to the cloud (I am assuming Ubuntu One or Dropbox). Just go to their respective website, log in, and you should be able to access your cloud files anywhere in the world, as long as you have an internet connection.